# Excel Macro to add, copy paste onto separate worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Please could someone offer some advice?

I have been asked to create a basic sheet that will include a button to add up three values, copy and paste them into another work sheet and repeat every time the button is pressed, with the added ability to shift down to the next row so previous values remain. Through some googling and playing, I have come up with the below. It carries out most of the needed function, except for the final part - pasting it onto a new row every time the button is pressed.

```
Sub Button3_Click()
Range("E9").Formula = "=SUM(E5:E7)"
Worksheets("Sheet2").Visible = True
Dim nextRow As Integer
'Find next empty row on Sheet2
  nextRow = Sheets(2).Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
'Copy Sheet1!E5:E9, Transpose to Sheet2
    Sheets(1).Range("E5:E9").Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("F6:J6").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

'Copy Sheet1!N20 to Column G
   Sheets(1).Range("N20").Copy Destination:=Sheets(2).Range("G" & nextRow)

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to be sure to qualify `Rows.Count` with the sheet you want it to run on, i.e. `nextRow = Sheets(2).Range("F" & Sheets(2).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1`.  Also, note that `Sheets("Sheet2")` is *not necessarily* the same as `Sheets(2)`.  `Sheets(2)` refers to the second sheet in the Index, not the sheet named "Sheet2".

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest explicitly defining the names:

```
Sub Button3_Click()

Range("E9").Formula = "=SUM(E5:E7)"
Set wsh2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set wsh1 = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Sheets(1)? make sure it's the first sheet or use Sheets(1)

wsh2.Visible = True

Dim nextRow As Integer
'Find next empty row on Sheet2
  nextRow = wsh2.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
'Copy Sheet1!E5:E9, Transpose to Sheet2
    wsh1.Range("E5:E9").Copy
    wsh2.Range("F6:J6").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

'Copy Sheet1!N20 to Column G
   wsh1.Range("N20").Copy Destination:=wsh2.Range("G" & nextRow)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you both for taking the time to consider my query and make suggestions. However I am missing somthing as both appear to have the same result. Once the button is clicked the data from the cells in Sheet 1 is copied to where I want it to in Sheet 2, however when I click again after entering diffrent data, the 2nd set of data writes over the original one - I am looking for the original data to shift down a row everytime new data is entered into sheet 1 and the button is pressed. I have used Masoud's suggestion and now Sheet 1 is called "Calc" and SHeet 2 is "Result"